# How can i create a newsletter for my wp blog?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, newsletter

I own a blog and finally wants that my users should be able to get a weekly newsletter on the blog. Basically I am a new user of wordpress and not sure how i can do that. I got some material on internet how can i create a weekly newsletter but all are paid services and right now I wont be able to afford them. Can anyone help me out???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally advise against running the newsletter from your server directly as their can be issues with delivery rates and mails being flagged as spam.

Instead http://www.mailchimp.com have a free user plan that would be suitable for you; as they are a premium service provider you can feel more confident that your email delivery rates are going to be higher than the aforementioned.

There is also a MailChimp plugin for WordPress that helps you integrate with their service.

Comment: You can also set up an rss campaign, so an email automatically gets sent periodically when new content is posted.

Comment: @Drai yes i am using feedburner for the same. But i want a weekly newsletter kind of thing; so that we can embed ads as well in them. They would be kind of source of income.

Comment: will try this... it seems better then other :)

Comment: @amod0017 What i meant is that Mailchimp (and others) allow you to enter your feedburner URL into a template which you can style and then set the frequency.It won't send unless there is new content, and will only send on the period you specify, and it can pull all of the text and images (or just excerpt with read more link) from the posts.I have not tested this with ads. Apologies is you knew this already. Also Mailchimp has a RSS mixer where you can mash-up multiple feeds. here are some links http://blog.mailchimp.com/tag/rss-to-email/
http://chimpfeedr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Search plugins: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=newsletter